# Basic Auth with Harvest API works on Postman, not on site

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

WHen using postman, my harvest api basic auth credentials work fine, and I get the data back I need. When I try the same thing with ajax I get a 401 credentials error.

```
$.ajax({


dataType: 'jsonp',
type: 'POST',
url: "https://harvest.greenhouse.io/v1/offices",
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username"));
}
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I have tried copying the 64bit code that POSTMAN generates instead of using btoa("user") but that does not work either. The password is supposed to be blank.

What might I be missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to use headers instead of setRequestHeader? Also, btoa should use the username and password, I believe. Like, use the string username + ':' + password to make the base64

Comment: Yes, that did not help. I have also tried just copying the 64 bit code generated by postman and that did not work either

Comment: @RyanY I have the same problem now. I can't do JSONP because the server does not send JSONP and I cannot change anything in the server. I just don't see Authorization key in the request header. What did you end up doing?